# Prove In Equilateral Triangle $ABC$ $AM$ and $AN$ are equal

Tags: geometry

> $\triangle ABC$ is a equilateral triangle. Line $xy$ passes through vertex $A$ (but doesn't intersect any sides of triangle). $H$ is a point on line $xy$ which is angle bisector of $\angle HAB$ and exterior angle of $B$ intersects each other at $M$. $I$ is a point on line $xy$ which is angle bisector of $\angle IAC$ and exterior angle of $C$ intersects each other at $N$. Prove $AN = AM$.

Here is the figure for for clarification:[image]

*Things I have done so far:* I tried using similar triangles like $ACK$ and $ABG$ and using angle bisector theorem to prove $AN=AM$ but I was not succesful.

Comment: **Hint:** $N\in(MJ)$ is the incenter of $ACJ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that $N$ and $M$ lies on the angle bisector of $\angle BJA$. It follows that $$\angle ANM=\angle NAJ+\angle JAN=30^\circ.$$
Similarly, 
$$\angle AMN=\angle MAH-\angle AJM=30^\circ.$$
Thus $\angle ANM=\angle AMN (=30^\circ).$

Comment: How do you get $\angle ANM = \angle NAJ + \angle JAN = 30^\circ$? From exterior angles, I see that $\angle ANM = \angle NAJ + \angle BAM$.

Comment: shouldn't that be $\angle AMN=\angle MAH-\angle AJM=30^\circ$ instead?

Comment: @Mick: Yes, fixed.